# Why i can't access one of the html element's attribute value, but i can access other ones using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes

1) Why can i only access the id attribute's value but the rest logs undefined using this code?

2) How can i access them in a different way?

```js
$('.block').click(function() {
  console.log(this.id); // is defined
  console.log(this.class); // undefined
  console.log(this.value) // undefined
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="game-wrap">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="block" id="block1" value="1"> </div>
      <div class="block" id="block2" value="2"> </div>
      <div class="block" id="block3" value="3"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) property to access `class` attribute of the specified element. `console.log(this.className);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### this.class

`class` is a reserved keyword in Javascript and older versions of IE couldn't properly interpret it when used as an object property. Because of this, the `Element` property that corresponds to an HTML tag's `class` attribute is `className`.
In other words, it should be `this.className`

FYI, it's the same thing with the `for` attribute on `<label>` tags, the corresponding property is `htmlFor`

#### this.value

The `value` property is only applicable to form elements. The `value` attribute is non-standard for other tags but you can still access the attribute value by calling `this.getAttribute('value')`. However, custom attributes like this should be prefixed with `data-`, so it should be

`<div class="block" id="block1" data-value="1"> </div>`

and

`this.getAttribute('data-value')` or `$(this).attr('data-value')`

Comment: so how would i access the value node?

Comment: @DavisDavis See my updated answer. Only form elements have the `value` property.

Comment: @DavisDavis It's not just better practice, the HTML5 specification states that attributes prefixed with `data-` is to be considered proprietary and left intact by the browser. Browsers are free to completely discard any non-standard and non-proprietary attributes (such as `value` on `<div>` tags) but I'm not aware of any browser that actually do this.

Comment: Thanks Mikael for your explanation !

Answer (score 1):

Use [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) property to access `class` attribute of the specified element.

```
console.log(this.className);
```

And `div` element doesn't have `value` property instead use [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)/[`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property

```
console.log(this.textContent); //this.innerHTML
```

And to store arbitrary data use `data-*` prefixed attribute which can be accessed using [`Element.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property

```
<div class="block" id="block2" data-value="2"> 2</div>
```

```js
$('.block').click(function() {
  console.log(this.id); // is defined
  console.log(this.className); // undefined
  console.log(this.dataset.value) // undefined

  //JQuery
  console.log($(this).prop("id"));
  console.log($(this).attr("class"));
  console.log($(this).data("value"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="block" id="block1" data-value="1">1 </div>
<div class="block" id="block2" data-value="2"> 2</div>
<div class="block" id="block3" data-value="3"> 3</div>
```

Comment: Or the OP could make use of the `data-` attribute if the OP doesn't want the value to match the content of the div. Example `<div class="block" id="block1" data-value="1">1</div>` and use `console.log($(this).attr('data-value'));` https://jsfiddle.net/ryyuj7kp/ if you like this suggestion feel free to add it into your answer.

Comment: @NewToJS, Good point; added to answer; however instead of `$(this).attr('data-value')` I recommended `$(this).data('value')`

Comment: Ah yeah, wasn't aware of `.data('')` as I try to avoid jQuery but I am sure I will remember for future suggestions or use if any. Thank you :) I have noticed many are offering a hacky solution of `.attr('value');` *facepalms* I see of no reason to offer a hacky solution since this is the reason for having `dataset`

Answer (score 0):

try this

To get class

```
console.log($(this).attr("class"));
```

To get value

```
console.log($(this).attr("value"));
```

Comment: but `value` isn't really a `div` property so this is just a hacky way of doing it. I would just suggest using the `data-` attribute if it's a must.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the right jQuery function to access the attributes.

```
 $('.block').click(function(){
    console.log( $(this).attr('id') ); 
    console.log( $(this).attr('class') ); 
    console.log( $(this).attr('value') ); 
 });
```

Comment: but `value` isn't really a `div` property so this is just a hacky way of doing it. I would just suggest using the `data-` attribute if it's a must.

Comment: I know but if you put it the the browser will render it even though it has no idea what it is. It won't do anything else with it but you can still access it. You can use it to store custom data and prevent it from clashing with another library. Try it. It works and you may find it useful one day. P.S. I wouldn't use value as my custom attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```js
 $('.block').click(function(){
    console.log(this.id); // is defined
    console.log(this.className); // undefined
    console.log($(this).attr('value')) // undefined
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
         <div class="game-wrap">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="block" id="block1" value="1">test 1 </div>
               <div class="block" id="block2" value="2"> 2</div>
               <div class="block" id="block3" value="3"> 3</div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `value` is not a valid attribute for a div element, and `class` attribute is referenced in Javascript by `className`. Instead of value you should look at html5 `data-*` attribute, which allows you to embed any arbitrary data you want.

For example:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="game-wrap">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="block" id="block1" data-value="1" data-best-dinosaur="T-Rex"> </div>
      <div class="block" id="block2" data-value="2" data-best-dinosaur="Stegosaurus"> </div>
      <div class="block" id="block3" data-value="3" data-best-dinosaur="Diplodocus"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $('.block').click(function() {
    console.log(this.id);
    console.log(this.className);
    console.log(this.dataset.value)
    console.log(this.dataset.bestDinosaur);
  });
</script>
```